# Using VBA to name ranges and create charts with those ranges

Tags: vba, excel, charts, range

I'm new to VBA. I'm attempting to create over 500 xlClusteredColumn charts using two columns of information and I'd like to expedite the work. The first column contains names I'd like to use for named ranges (i.e.: *Line1*, *Line2*, etc.) and the second column contains the indirect references of the data ranges (i.e., `Sheet1!C4:D28`, `Sheet1!C28:D90`). I noticed that if I use a named range for the "Chart Data Series" field, the data shows up nicely (but I have to first create that named range being sure to include the `INDIRECT` formula in the reference, (e.g.: Named Range *Line1* is equal to `=INDIRECT(Sheet1!C4:C28)`). The ranges will be static.

In reviewing prior questions I couldn't seem to find a solution that would select the first cell in this set and name it, then uses the second cell to define that range. I think I might need the `ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=` formula and combine it with a loop (but I couldn't get it to use a selection or cell to define the Add Name aspect, only a hard coded name).

If the solution requires it, I can go back and extract the individual ranges (i.e.: `C4:D28`) from the cell and have the chart reference only that if it makes the code simpler. I know my first outlined attempt isn't the only solution and there's probably one much more elegant. I figured using named ranges would speed up the chart work, but perhaps there's a way to cut that step out?

Populating a new sheet with all the charts for each of these ranges would be icing on the cake, but I'll be happy enough receiving help to get the data set up to chart.

Example information:

**NameRange1** (let's say in cells A1:A4)

WKD_1_NB

WKD_2_EB

WKD_3_EB
**SerRange1** (in cells B1:B4)

WKDpivot!C4:D43

WKDpivot!C84:D140

WKDpivot!C197:D233

(Chart data range requires the reference of named range "WKD_1_NB" to be '=INDIRECT(WKDpivot!C4:D43)' in order for the chart to work.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Given the ranges don't need to be dynamic, why don't you just name your range with Insert|Name|Define.

Comment: Hi @PA, thanks for your suggestion.  I have 546 ranges (and charts) so if I could do something to iterate the process it would speed up the process.

Comment: Oh, I see, this changes a lot... edit your question with new info,

Comment: Not sure I understand why you need to use the `Indirect` function. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @David: I found out if I use a named range (let's say _Line1_) for a chart specifically in the "Chart data range" field, it populates a chart easily. However, to make a named range with the setup I have, I have to first create the named range (_Line1_), then add the `INDIRECT` function to the reference (`Sheet1!C4:D28`) since one of the columns has those ranges already created. I'm sorry if I'm not explaining this well. I should probably edit the question and add some tables or something.

Comment: what I don't understand is why you are using `Indirect`.  Why can't you just put `=WKD_1_NB` in the chart data range formula?

Comment: @David because they haven't been defined yet. I only experimented with the first few named ranges and happened to see that a named range works in a chart data range. I'd like to figure out some code to create these 549 named ranges, then go back and use those named ranges to create the charts. I was thinking something like a two step process: create the ranges in one loop, go back and cycle through those ranges to create charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so why don't you try the two-step process. I am going to do this without `Indirect` because I don't see that it is necessary.

```
Sub CreateNames()
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim myName As String
Dim addr As String

Set rng = Range("A1:A2") '## Modify as needed
For Each r In rng.Cells
    myName = r.Value
    addr = "=" & r.Offset(0, 1).Value
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add myName, addr

Next

End Sub
```

This creates your names (screenshot). Note there are some rules about naming conventions and allowable names, etc., the code above does not take any of these in to account.

[image]

From there it should be fairly simple to create a loop that adds your charts one by one, and assigns each named range to each chart.

Comment: Thanks very much!  It took me a bit to realize I had to be sure to have these names and ranges on a new sheet at the top of the page with no headers (or change the offset values) and I think also to have the *Use Relative References* off, but this seemed to do the trick to quickly make all my ranges. And you're right, the `INDIRECT` function is not needed once the ranges are created via your method. Much obliged for your help!

Comment: You could have headers, just start the range at "A2" (or wherever else!) instead of "A1".  You could also use a different offset value if the reference is located in a different column, etc.  Cheers!

Comment: You're right, and as I've been working on it, it looks like I need to have the cursor in A1 when I run the module, though I added absolute references ($) so I wasn't being very scientific about what was changing what. I was playing around with the offset values and a change in ranges to see how it behaves. In any case, I got all 549 references completed thanks to you!